# Update all rows from table with loop and prefix

Tags: mysql

I'm new in MySQL. I have table "books", in table is column ISBN. How can I update this column for all rows?

I have to complete all the lines with ISBN according to the key: BOOK0001, BOOK0002, BOOK0003... (where BOOK is a prefix).

I have something like this for this moment but I'm not sure if I mean it right:

```
SET @isbn=0;
UPDATE books SET isbn = (@isbn:=@isbn+1) ORDER BY isbn;
```

Can I count on a hint?

Comment: If you aren't in a position to test this locally you could use a fiddle eg https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE books
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @isbn:=0) init_var
SET isbn = CONCAT('BOOK', LPAD(@isbn:=@isbn+1, 4, 0));
```